# ValueError "Expected version spec" when installing local wheel via pip

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, python-wheel

I have a closed-source Python module I am developing and would like to share with people in my workplace.  I have built a wheel via `setup.py bdist_wheel` with this setup.py file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(name='mypkg',
      version='0.0.1',
      description='tools for work',
      author='tbhartman',
      packages=find_packages('src', exclude=['test*']),
      package_dir = {'':'src'},
      entry_points={
          'console_scripts':[
              'runtool = mypkg.run:main',
              ],
          },
      install_requires = ['argparse'],
      classifiers = [
          'Development Status :: 3 - Alpha',
          'Programming Language :: Python :: 2',
          ]
     )
```

I want to test the installation process, so I try
    pip install dist\mypkg-0.0.1-py2-none-any.whl
and get the following traceback:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 139, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 235, in run
    InstallRequirement.from_line(name, None))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 118, in from_line
    return cls(req, comes_from, url=url)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 43, in __init__
    req = pkg_resources.Requirement.parse(req)
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2929, in parse
    reqs = list(parse_requirements(s))
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2876, in parse_requirements
    "version spec")
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2841, in scan_list
    raise ValueError(msg, line, "at", line[p:])
ValueError: ('Expected version spec in', 'dist/mypkg-0.0.1-py2-none-any.whl', 'at', '/mypkg-0.0.1-py2-none-any.whl')

Storing complete log in C:\Users\tbhartman\pip\pip.log
```

What is the problem and how to I fix it?

Comment: It appears that `pip` is trying to search from an index for `mypkg-0.0.1-py2-none-any.whl`, but it has trouble parsing that string to get a package/version.  How do I tell `pip` to just use the wheel file, rather than searching for a package?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I was using a very out-of-date version of PIP.

```
$ pip -V
pip 1.3.1 from C:\Python27\lib\site-packages (python 2.7)
```

I upgraded to `pip 6.0.8` and all is well.

Comment: Just use `pip install --upgrade pip` to upgrade pip

Comment: In very old versions, you may need to run `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

Answer (score 30):

Using the Ubuntu 14.04 AMI on AWS, I found I had to upgrade `setuptools`:

```
sudo pip3 install -vU setuptools
```

Comment: Works like a charm. I had the same problem, this fixed it.